# CodenameOne format number

Tags: codenameone

I have a textfield in which user enters the amount. Is there a way to format the text in a textfield to display it as a decimal number etc. "123.456,10". I would like to format it as the user types. I tried to play with listener on that field but no luck.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes.
you have to choose decimal constraint in designer which is also shown in given image[image]

Comment: I've tried that already but it doesn't work. I get the numeric keyboard but the number I enter stays just as I entered it.

Comment: There is no way to do that during text entry since the entry is handled by the native subsystem. You can do this after the fact by invoking setText on the field.